# Page viewer not displaying ssrs report as it

Tags: reporting-services, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

Scenario:
I have created report inside ssrs and want to display the same into sharepoint.
The page take URL Parameter hence we have created html page and add the URL into the iframe and then added the htm file into the page viewer.
Problem:
The Webpage is displaying the report, but not in the format same as in the source it has got long scroll and the table inside the report the width has increased where as i have not applied any css into the html page nor to the Iframe.
There are now three scroll to the html page, page viwer and the parent page.
I just want it to get the report as it is on the source and also only scroll which is allowed is the page scroll.
Please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this to display report using page viewer web part.

https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/page-viewer-as-report-viewer/